# Parent User and Child User - relate users

Tags: user-roles, user-meta, user-access, wp-user-query

I need to create a system in which I have 2 types of users: Company User (C) and Employee User (E).

I need C to be able to register as many E as necessary and for C users to be able to publish articles that will only be visible to E users, children of C users.

I figured it would be possible to do this with meta fields so I created the ACF DAD and CHILD field with Jet Engine plugin. I couldn't but I didn't succeed.
Can anyone **tell me if it is possible to use metafields for this**?

Comment: Have you tried role and metafield together? Using role you can define the user's capabilities and allow User C to publish articles, without compromising the entire site taking away his ability to mess with plugins, themes and other settings.

For metafields I would suggest a logic like:
Meta user_type_employ for the User E, puting User C ID in this meta field.

Maybe this makes it possible:
Be able to filter the articles for the employee of each company using the user C ID recorded in the user_type_employ meta and list the posts based on the posts' author ID.

Comment: @AbnerSamuel created a specific Role with the plugin. I gave the ability to edit and publish posts. But with the user meta I'm not having success. Can you point me to a plugin, if it is possible to do this with a plugin?